# What is $\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k}^3$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

Having a little trouble determining if there is a closed form expression for $\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k}^3$.

Trying to solve a larger problem from Peter Cameron's Combinatorics book (Dixon's Identity) and trying to determine this identity to help with it.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the matter? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Have you computed some small values?

Comment: Ya I tried computing some small values, the main problem I'm trying to solve is from Peter Cameron's Combinatorics book, and I'm trying to determine this identity to help with that question.

Comment: Calculate the first few values & then consult OEIS. https://oeis.org/A000172 ... Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @DonaldSplutterwit

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1352001p7387371

Comment: Thanks @JeanMarie